# Bundle array of json/File/user-defined objects in Android

Tags: android, arrays, json

how to bundle array of File objects or array of Json objects or array of user-defined objects in one activity and send it to another and how to access them correctly. ?

Primitive types like string is quite easy with

```
Intent in = new Intent();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("name", "test");
in.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(in);
```

Some reading suggested to use Parcelable , some serializable !! What is the right way and how to do it. ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JSON already then it's plain old text and you don't need fancy inter-process mechanisms to serialise it.

Personally I'd favour Parcelable over Serializable any day of the week - unless you're writing to permanent storage - but to be sure I'd need to know a little more about the problem you're trying to solve...

What is activity 2 going to be doing with the data from activity 1? Will activity 2 be okay using it's own copy of the data, or would you expect changes it makes to be visible to activity 1?